# How can I train a LSTM model with multiple time series datasets?

Tags: python, neural-network, dataset, lstm, predict

I have multiple time series datasets which I formatted to look in the next way:

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|         X       |        Y         |
+-----------------+------------------+
| [0.1, 0.3, 0.4] | [0.5, 0.8, 0.9]  |
+-----------------+------------------+
| [0.3, 0.4, 0.5] | [0.8, 0.9, 0.91] |
+-----------------+------------------+
| [0.4, 0.5, 0.8] | [0.9, 0.91, 0.93]|
+-----------------+------------------+
|       ...       |       ...        |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

For each dataset, X contains the vector of values to inspect to perform the prediction (predict the next 3 values), and Y contains the vector of the next 3 values to be predicted.

I have multiple datasets like the mentioned above, and many other datasets to be predicted only containing the X part.

My question is, how can I fit the LSTM network in order to train with the information of all the training datasets? Can I concatenate their X values on the one hand, and the Y values on the other hand?

I have the following code, but I am not sure if it is good implemented.

```
# listadx and listady are lists containing the concatenation of X and Y vectors of all the datasets, respectively.

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(listadx) * 0.67)
test_size = len(listadx) - train_size

trainx, testx = listadx[0:train_size,:], listadx[train_size:len(listadx),:]
trainy, testy = listady[0:train_size,:], listady[train_size:len(listady),:]



# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainx = numpy.reshape(trainx, (trainx.shape[0], 1, trainx.shape[1]))
testx = numpy.reshape(testx, (testx.shape[0], 1, testx.shape[1]))



# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(trainx.shape[1], trainx.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(outputs))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)


# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainx)
testPredict = model.predict(testx)
```

trainPredict returns me a vector with 3 values. Are those the values of Y?

Comment: HI did you ever find an answer to this question?